# Automatically add columns to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an MSSQL table with no id column, mainly because I accidentally dropped it and so recreated the column. Is there a way in SQL of automatically adding values to it so I don't have to manually sit there putting an ID number?

Comment: and make the column auto-increment. In SQL SERVER it is called IDENTITY

Comment: Bear in mind that if you have a relation from other tables to the id of that table and assign new ids in the existing records you also need to update the ids in the other tables

Answer (score 1):

Use a CTE for an initial repopulation:

```
with CTE as
(
select t1.*, row_number() over (order by AnyColumn) as RN
from MyTable t1
)
update CTE
set ID = RN
```

Comment: John I think ID is blank so how can check set ID = RN

Answer (score 0):

Solutions 1:  Restore Latest Backup on test DB then updated Id's in New Column

Solutions 2:  Update Id's From Other Relational table based on column mapping .